# LInux Kernel API to find the vma corresponds to a virtual address

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

Is there any Kernel API to find the VMA corresponds to virtual address?

Example : if a have an address 0x13000 i need some function like below

```
 struct vm_area_struct *vma =  vma_corresponds_to (0x13000,task);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `find_vma` in `linux/mm.h`.

```
/* Look up the first VMA which satisfies  addr < vm_end,  NULL if none. */
extern struct vm_area_struct * find_vma(struct mm_struct * mm, unsigned long addr);
```

This should do the trick:

```
struct vm_area_struct *vma = find_vma(task->mm, 0x13000);
if (vma == NULL)
    return -EFAULT;
if (0x13000 >= vma->vm_end)
    return -EFAULT;
```

Comment: @Dhyan Your edit was correct, the function definition changed in v2.0.19. Somebody else rejected it but I've corrected it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Since v5.14-rc1, there is a new API in `linux/mm.h` called `vma_lookup()`

The code can now be reduced to the following:

```
struct vm_area_struct *vma = vma_lookup(task->mm, 0x13000);

if (!vma)
    return -EFAULT;
```